# how can I check argument size in class constructor in c++

Tags: c++

for example:

```
class Static {
public:
    Static(std::vector<int> v) {
        if (v.size() ! = 3) {
            //...
        }
    }
    ~Static() {
        std::cout << "Static dtor\n";
    }
};
```

I have class named `Static`, and its constructor has a argument `v`, how can I check `v`'size, and if `v.size() < 3`, the constructor exit

many answers say that it can be solved by using `throw` a exception, but the problem is that the destructor will not be call.

so I wonder whether `return` will be ok, for examples:

```
class Static {
public:
    Static(std::vector<int> v) {
        if (v.size() ! = 3) {
            //to log some error info
            return;
        }
    }
    ~Static() {
        std::cout << "Static dtor\n";
    }
};
```

Comment: If you throw an exception in the constructor, the object is never fully constructed so the destructor *should not* be called.

Comment: "many answers say that it can be solved by using throw a exception, but the problem is that the destructor will not be call" - of course the destructor will not be called - the object is not fully constructed yet.

Comment: In case of exception, whereas `~Static` is not called, destructor of already initialized members would be called.

Comment: Why not write the constructor to accept an `std::array<int, 3>`?   That way, any attempt to pass something with more than three elements will be diagnosed by the compiler (or in code that populates the array, if needed).   No need to worry about enforcing that by making the constructor fail.

Answer (score 1):

> so I wonder whether return will be ok, for examples:

Most probably that's not OK, because it leaves you with a `Static` instance in an invalid and improperly initialized state.

The only way to avoid that, and keep everything clean is throwing an exception.

---

Assumed you want to manage a `std:.vector<int>` with a fixed size of 3 internally, it would be better to rewrite your constructor like

```
Static(int a, int b, int c) {
    v_.push_back(a);
    v_.push_back(b);
    v_.push_back(c);
}
```

Comment: but after calling throw, `~Static()`  will not be called, so it will be better to use `shared_ptr` in `~Static()`?

Comment: @wang 1st time you're telling anything about pointers here. Generally it would be better to use a smart pointer if you have some dynamic allocations. These will be guaranteed to be destructed properly.